# Which port does WebRequest use by default?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I was asked by a network admin which port my code

```
        webReq = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create(Me.Files(fileNr).URL), HttpWebRequest)
        webResp = CType(webReq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
```

uses / requires to be open.

If no port is specified, does it always use TCP port 8080?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server host. Does the URL look like http://google.com or like http://172.217.20.14:80?

In the second scenario the port is what follows the colon(:) character.
In the first one, someone must have configured a (internal?)DNS server so that http://google.com gets mapped to a numerical IP address such as http://172.217.20.14:80.